# ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref?

Tags: python, docker

**I tried docker to run program parliament2, facing import error issue ?**

docker run dnanexus/parliament2:hgsc -h 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dnanexus/parliament2.py", line 3, in 
    import argparse
  File "/miniconda/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 86, in 
    import copy as _copy
  File "/miniconda/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 52, in 
    import weakref
  File "/miniconda/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in 
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref